# Magento 1.9.2 - new order emails not queuing

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, transactional-mail

Im facing an issue with **new order e-mails**.

As far as I know, magento uses cronjob to send emails previously stored in `core_email_queue` table.
I configured cron and it works fine - it seems that cron is not a problem.

When i click Send Email,  notify customer by email or anything in admin panel it works just fine. Message appears in the table and after a minute or so it is send.

The problem is when a customer places an order, email does not appear in `core_email_queue` table.

Order email sending is enabled in `sales email` tab.

**What I've already tried:**

**Adding:**

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

line to `cron.php` file.

**Did not work.**

**Changing**

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

**to:**

```
$mailer->send();
```

in `Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`

**Did not work.**

**Do you guys have any idea, what can be wrong or how could I check where the problem is?**

Comment: Did you Check transcation mail preview

Comment: Yes I did, it looks fine. Also I can send order email via admin panel manually, so it seems that is not the problem.